# Test app for samsung smart tv on emulator

Tags: android-emulator, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-emulator

I am building a remote control in android for samsung smart tvs. I don't have a smasung smart tv to check my android remote, so I want to test it with some kind of emulator on my computer.

is there such a thing? some kind of smasung smart tv emulator that runs on windows?

Answer (score 0):

there is a emulator for different versions of Tizen Smart TV. You can check it in https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/tv-emulator.html

You should also check the limitation of the emulator vs a real TV set https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/tv-emulator/emulator-limitations.html

Best regards

Comment: Thank you, though I have tried to install their emulator on windows 10, but I have many issues with their bridge connection with the emulator.
When I try to use a bridge connection, after following their instructions, it says: `network bridge is not ready to pass packets`. any ideas?

Comment: I had also many issues trying to set the network adapter as bridge. In my case I configured it in NAT mode creating all port forwarding rules, but I don't know if it could be works for remote control (check if there is a dedicated port to apply port forwarding)

Comment: How can I also config this port forwarding?

Comment: Please check the "Controlling the Network Setting" point in the general proposal documentation of Tizen
https://docs.tizen.org/application/vstools/tools/emulator-control-panel/